# In SQL Server Management Studio 2014, the New Trigger menu option is disabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express, triggers, management-studio-express

[image]

I want to add a new trigger to my table. As seen in the picture, New Trigger button is not active. new index, new column, new contraints, new statics is active.

I do not understand what is the problem.

Comment: What happens when you use `Create trigger triggername...`

Comment: Seems like SQL SERVER bug check this https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/873249/ssms-2014-new-trigger-is-disabled-for-older-2012-2008r2-versions-of-sql-server

Answer (score 20):

You don't need to use the menu item to create a trigger. Just open up a query window and write the [create trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) statement there.

To get some help with the syntax you can use a snippet in the editor. Right click on the surface of the query editor and select Insert Snippet and then select Trigger and Create Trigger to get the following code snippet inserted to your editor.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName
    ON [dbo].[TableName]
    FOR DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    END
```

The menu item (if you get it to work) will do almost the same thing only it will use a template that looks like this:

```
-- ================================================
-- Template generated from Template Explorer using:
-- Create Trigger (New Menu).SQL
--
-- Use the Specify Values for Template Parameters 
-- command (Ctrl-Shift-M) to fill in the parameter 
-- values below.
--
-- See additional Create Trigger templates for more
-- examples of different Trigger statements.
--
-- This block of comments will not be included in
-- the definition of the function.
-- ================================================
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE TRIGGER <Schema_Name, sysname, Schema_Name>.<Trigger_Name, sysname, Trigger_Name> 
   ON  <Schema_Name, sysname, Schema_Name>.<Table_Name, sysname, Table_Name> 
   AFTER <Data_Modification_Statements, , INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE>
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for trigger here

END
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was asked here: [SQL Server Express 'NEW TRIGGER' BUTTON IS DISABLED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645357/sql-server-express-new-trigger-button-is-disabled/43374977#43374977)

I hope this can help you!